# What cube deployment changes will force a reprocess?

Tags: ssas, cube, ssas-2008

Sometimes when I deploy a cube that has been changed (from BIDS), I can continue to browse the existing cube data.  Other times, the engine insists I reprocess the data before I can browse the cube.

I can't find a definitive resource showing which changes require a data reprocess and which do not.

SSAS 2008.

Comment: Try this: http://bimic.blogspot.com/2011/08/ssas-which-change-makes-cubedimension.html

Comment: That'll do nicely.  Thanks.  Stick that in as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you need to process when

- adding or editing measures
- adding a dimension attribute
- editing dimension attribute relationships or order by properties

A more complete list can be found [here](http://bimic.blogspot.com/2011/08/ssas-which-change-makes-cubedimension.html).