# Should I process whole cube when ever I create new calculated measure, attribute changes

Tags: ssas, cube, msbi

Our SSAS cube are in development stage. We have around 40 million records in couple of fact table in data warehouse.

If I create new calculate measure or if I do some changes in the dimension, Should I process the hole cube?

I am concern about this because as we have high volumes of data, processing of cubes is taking time.

And also Which type of process suits when I made such changes.

Please guide me.

Comment: And also When I make some changes in dimensions and process it, I am not able to browse cube from ssms. Should I have to wait till cube is processed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What cube deployment changes will force a reprocess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705462/what-cube-deployment-changes-will-force-a-reprocess)

Answer (score 0):

I know that you ve posted a long time ago but I just crossed your question maybe my answer can help some people ;)

Newly defined calculated members will not appear in the Calculation Tools pane until these objects have been deployed. Calculations do not require processing
Find more details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-tutorial/lesson-6-1-defining-calculated-members?view=asallproducts-allversions

if u do some changes in the dimension, you have to process just make sure that you don't forget anything to add before the process if it takes long.

I hope it helps :)